# How to run a core web application using the command line?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, web

I've created a core web app in VS2017 and I want to zip my project and send it to someone, so that he'll be able to run it using a command line (don't ask why plz).

I've tried to use `dotnet run` but it gives me this error:

```
 error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.4\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found.
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Seems only code was distributed and VS 2017 is not installed. If VS 2017 is installed, matching version of .NET Core SDK (1.0.4) is missing.